# Long boot time after using gparted to resize partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, bluetooth, gparted, dmesg

I recently used gparted to increase my ubuntu partition's size. Now, the startup time is super long. When i run `dmesg` I get (let me know if you want the full text. Below is just certain parts)

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.3.0-26-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-039) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1-generic 5.3.13)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic root=UUID=02ab8d62-1cd9-42f8-bdbb-bad102423862 ro quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr vt.handoff=1
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
[    1.986934] usb 1-10: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x3 has wMaxPacketSize 0, skipping
[    1.986935] usb 1-10: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x83 has wMaxPacketSize 0, skipping
[    1.986938] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0aaa, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    1.986939] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.994692] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:046D:C077.0002/input/input5
[    1.994899] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[    1.994916] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.994917] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   32.017615] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
[   32.017632] nvme 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   32.017648] nvme 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [15b7:5003] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
[   32.017658] nvme 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[   33.084138] fbcon: Taking over console
[   33.084267] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
[   33.098679] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   33.204386] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   33.224495] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   33.226315] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <akash-ZenBook-UX461FN-UX461FN>.
[   33.226888] Lockdown: systemd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   33.253575] Lockdown: systemd: BPF is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   33.253580] systemd[1]: File /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service:35 configures an IP firewall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling.
[   33.253581] systemd[1]: Proceeding WITHOUT firewalling in effect! (This warning is only shown for the first loaded unit using IP firewalling.)
[   33.298348] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   33.298400] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   33.298452] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   33.298517] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[   33.298540] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   33.307234] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   33.317374] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   33.319999] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   33.365535] systemd-journald[415]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   33.448249] ACPI Warning: \_SB.IETM._TRT: Return Package has no elements (empty) (20190703/nsprepkg-96)
[   35.138904] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   35.139464] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1424920 usecs
[   35.139681] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[   35.152652] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12797 usecs
[   35.152839] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-17-16-1.ddc
[   35.159691] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  123.639374] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  123.639375] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  123.639380] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  124.004917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  124.119969] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  124.186294] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  127.423852] wlo1: authenticate with 10:56:11:6a:83:7f
[  127.433556] wlo1: send auth to 10:56:11:6a:83:7f (try 1/3)
[  127.473871] wlo1: authenticated
[  127.475876] wlo1: associate with 10:56:11:6a:83:7f (try 1/3)
[  127.478539] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 10:56:11:6a:83:7f (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=7)
[  127.479920] wlo1: associated
[  127.514073] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  127.593159] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by 10:56:11:6a:83:7f
[  134.066942] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  134.066960] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  148.195885] kauditd_printk_skb: 34 callbacks suppressed
[  148.195886] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556878.554:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2358 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[  149.893845] traps: gnome-system-mo[2358] trap int3 ip:7f157961ea13 sp:7ffd9b3cda60 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6200.6[7f15795b9000+13f000]
[  170.264990] traps: gnome-system-mo[2534] trap int3 ip:7ff8d6a2aa13 sp:7ffd42226d50 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6200.6[7ff8d69c5000+13f000]
[  217.701939] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556948.567:47): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" pid=3373 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  217.776522] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556948.643:48): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.gnome-system-monitor" pid=3372 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  217.786133] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556948.651:49): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3375 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  217.786136] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556948.651:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=3375 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  217.791793] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556948.659:51): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=3377 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  217.792598] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556948.659:52): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=3378 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  218.285391] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556949.151:53): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" pid=3387 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  218.397576] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556949.263:54): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.gnome-system-monitor" pid=3386 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  218.404175] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556949.271:55): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3394 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  218.404179] audit: type=1400 audit(1595556949.271:56): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=3394 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  222.807545] kauditd_printk_skb: 32 callbacks suppressed
```

There are a few big spikes. One from 1.99 to 32, another from 35 to 123, and one more from 170 to 217. I looked at a few posts like this one [Boot much slower after partition resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643352/boot-much-slower-after-partition-resize) and [Very slow boot with Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639559/very-slow-boot-with-ubuntu-15-04) and [Is Bluetooth responsible for my Ubuntu 16.04 much slower startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826000/is-bluetooth-responsible-for-my-ubuntu-16-04-much-slower-startup) and perhaps that's my problem as well. But before doing anything dumb I want someone else's input.

Also when using gparted I did run into an error where the File System column for the swap partition went unknown and i had to right click -> Format To -> linux-swap.

Another useful (perhaps) thing is that I did what is described in [Nvidia card on an ASUS ZenBook Flip 14 sometimes boots to a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146394/nvidia-card-on-an-asus-zenbook-flip-14-sometimes-boots-to-a-purple-screen) (accepted answer) so I added `quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr` to the grub.

Comment: Did you delete? or delete then re-create any partitions (causing UUID to change), and thus a wait on boot for the UUID to appear (which it cannot) If so changing the UUID in your *file system table* (fstab) will stop the *long-wait* for the UUID to appear

Comment: I used gparted's resize/move option. Not sure if that deletes then re-creates.